# Opencart | Redirect to checkout success message

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I'm using opencart V4. I have new custom order controller. When an user click the create order button, It should create order and redirect to success page.

**Problem**

Now I'm able to create order successfully but not able to redirect to success page. It is redirecting index page. with url like this `www.domain.com/index.php?`

**Order twig file:**

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // Use 'POST' to send data to the server
            url: 'index.php?route=quickorder/create', // Adjust the URL to your controller
            data: orderData, // Include the payload data
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                // Handle the response from the server
                if (response.success) {
                    // Display a success message to the user (customize this)
                    alert('Custom order created successfully!');
                } else {
                    // Handle errors if necessary
                    alert(response);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
                // Handle AJAX errors
                alert('An error occurred while creating the custom order.');
            }
        });
```

**Controller file**

```
  $order_id = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($order_data);

                if ($order_id) {
                    $this->session->data['success'] = 'Your custom order has been successfully created!';
                    $this->session->data['order_id'] =  $order_id;
                  $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/success'));
            }
```

Order is creating successfully but not able to redirect `checkout/success`.

`alert(response);` also not working. It redirects to index.php?